# Android app to alert me when offline for a long time

Tags: android, monitoring, network-monitor, notification

I need an app to alert me when my Android phone goes offline for over 15 minutes. I have an obligation to respond to certain requests within a short time frame and they come to my phone over the net.

All I could find on Google Play are primitive apps that are not configurable and frontends to websites that monitor servers for me. Since I'm interested in my connection more than in any server downtime, it's not what I'm looking for.

Must haves for me:

- Ability to monitor a site without having to modify that site or set up a separate monitoring server.
- Downtime notifications with a customized sound.
- Don't alert me for the first missed connection, wait until the connection is not detected for a specific time. I don't want to scare everyone in the elevator when my WiFi and 4G go down for a minute.

It would be nice to have an option to override sound settings. Alerts are more important than phone calls for me when I'm on call.

Comment: There are many [automation apps]([Automatisierung (Profile-Switcher & Co)](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation)) which could be used for that; I have e.g. [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) in mind (link goes to the Tasker tag-wiki on Android.SE). Would such a solution be acceptable to you? Any price limit (Tasker is ~USD 5, but definitely worth it)?

Comment: Considering it's work related, the budget is pretty generous. On the other hand, I'd rather use a free program if I ever decide to recommend it to my colleagues. I don't want to advertise paid software.

Comment: Naming Tasker a "capable app" is probably an understatement :) There are some alternatives, but nothing comes real close if you're going for flexibility.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Sorry, I edited that part out, never expected you to reply that fast!

Comment: Too late :) And now you have an answer with some additional details. Hope you enjoy it :)

Answer (score 5):

**[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** might be an app to go with here. It doesn't come for free (there's a 7 day trial at their homepage, but then it's ~USD 5 if you really want to use it after that), and it requires some effort to get into it – but if you ask me, it's definitely worth it. Other apps from "the same section" ([Automation apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation)) might be able to achieve what you want, but I cannot speak for them: once you "got the kick", you stick with Tasker :)

The app works using "profiles", where a profile consists of conditions and tasks – basically "if this then that". It offers a lot of logic, such as loops, which comes in handy here. I cannot give you a ready-to-go profile, but the basic idea:

#### Condition

You want to trigger the task below when you're offline – which means no WiFi and no mobile connection. According to my [Tasker graphs](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_950), we have corresponding items in *State › Net*, namely "WiFi connected" (false) and "Mobile Network". So the entry condition would be: No mobile network, no WiFi connected → you're offline.

#### Task

Here I'd suggest a loop, having a *Tasker › Wait* for e.g. 30s at its start – followed by a check if you're still offline. Exit that loop (and task) if you're online again, the profile should become inactive then until you're again offline. Add a counter to the game: if that reaches 30, you're offline for at least 15min. Using that as trigger (counter greater than 30), have *Tasker* sending all the *Alerts* you want: Beep, Flash, Notify, Vibrate, whatever.

That's just the rudimentary concept – apply any fine-tuning you like :)

---

While not being affiliated with *Tasker* in any way, I'm a happy *Tasker* user for years. I've started with the 7-day trial, but bought the Pro straight away after only 3 days. Over at Android.SE we sometimes say, each 2nd issue can be solved using *Tasker* – so it's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

Try Server Monitor Pro App on Google Play, you can check from time to time your connection to Google's DNS and OpenDNS servers, if failed it alerts you.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not look promising. The screenshot with just one "Monitor Interval" setting suggests that there is no aggregation for failed requests.

Comment: Jorge, please explain in more details how the app works, thanks!